Office Pro Plus 2021 Retail via Office Deployment Tool install fails on Windows 11 23H2
Windows 11 Pro 23H2 Version 10.022621 (OS Build 22621.1848)
My windows setup is Local Account with full admin.
Office Pro Plus 2021 Retail
I have been trying for the last three days, including evenings when I really should have been enjoying family time, to use the Office deployment tool so I can only install the 64 bit versions word, Excel and Access - I do not want anything else.
I went to MS's online Office Customization Tool and created the below Configuration.xml.
I also downloaded deployment tool and it extracted the setup.exe and various configuration file examples and saved the Configuration.xml in the same folder called C:\Office2021Install
Before continuing I ran the MSRA Office removal tool to make sure my system was clean (It was).
I then mounted the Img file and made a note of the Drive Letter which I then appended that to the Configuration.xml that  I downloaded from MS's online Office Customization Tool.
First I tried using Windows 11 terminal as admin, opening it from within the C:\Office2021Install folder.
The command line I use to to run the deployment tool setup.exe is ".\setup.exe /configure Configuration.xml"
I am getting the error message
"We found a problem
We're sorry, we can't continue because we weren't able to download a required file.
Please make sure you're connected to the internet or connect to a different  network, then try again."
(My internet was connected and active)
I then opened Command Prompt from Win 11 task bar search as Admin and then navigated to C:\Office2021Install.
I then used the command "setup.exe /configure Configuration.xml "
I got the same error massage.
From what I can find online, this should work.
The reason that I am providing the "Setup64.exe" instead of the "Setup.exe" is that when I perform a normal install from the image I am  not given the choice to choose 32 bit or 64 bit.
I have also tried extracting the contents of the Office IMG file to a folder in the C: drive root, and pointing the SourcePath to that but  I get the same error.
I also tried just getting the full Office 2021 Pro Suite installed (as a test).
I mounted the ISO and ran setup, the whole thing installed without an error.
I then ran the MSRA Office removal tool, rebooted and in the Configuration file I changed SourcePath="F:\Office\Setup64.exe" to SourcePath="F:Setup.exe"
but now I get the Error Code 0-2039 (0)
"Couldn't Install
Is your internet working (Yes it is and it is active when I try to install Office)
Do you have enough free space on your main hard drive?"
(Yes. its a 2TB SSD with only 94.6 GB used).
I would be grateful for any help as the whole point of a local install is that not internet is required, except to register after the installation.
This is my configuration file created and exported from MS online  Office Customization Tool .
 <Configuration ID="7b438bdd-f6a0-48d4-b104-612e6a5ccc0e"> 
 <Info Description="" /> 
<Add OfficeClientEdition="64" Channel="Current" SourcePath="F:\Office\Setup64.exe" "AllowCdnFallback="TRUE">
<Product ID="ProPlus2021Retail" PIDKEY="My key goes here"> 
<Language ID="en-gb" /> 
<ExcludeApp ID="Groove" /> 
<ExcludeApp ID="Lync" /> 
<ExcludeApp ID="OneDrive" /> 
<ExcludeApp ID="OneNote" /> 
<ExcludeApp ID="Project" /> 
<ExcludeApp ID="Outlook" /> 
<ExcludeApp ID="PowerPoint" /> 
<ExcludeApp ID="Publisher" /> 
<ExcludeApp ID="Outlook" /> 
<ExcludeApp ID="Visio" /> 
</Product> 
</Add> 
<Property Name="SharedComputerLicensing" Value="0" /> 
<Property Name="FORCEAPPSHUTDOWN" Value="FALSE" /> 
<Property Name="DeviceBasedLicensing" Value="0" /> 
<Property Name="SCLCacheOverride" Value="0" /> 
<Property Name="AUTOACTIVATE" Value="1" /> 
<Updates Enabled="TRUE" /> 
<RemoveMSI /> 
<AppSettings> 
<Setup Name="Company" Value="My name goes here" /> 
</AppSettings> 
<Display Level="Full" AcceptEULA="TRUE" /> 
</Configuration> ```

This is the Office Deployment Tool Folder
[![This is the Office Deployment Tool Folder][1]][1]


This is the setup file in the mounted office IMG
[![This is the setup file in the mounted office IMG][2]][2]


  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/pBhaVdHf.jpg
  [2]: https://i.sstatic.net/FhNfcMVo.jpg


You didn’t provide the configuration file. I am fairly certain that Office 2021 and newer is 64-bit only.

You do need a configuration file is you only wish to install specific programs from the office suite as I stated in my OP.

I have used the configuration tool hundreds of times. You didn’t provide the configuration file. Please [exit] your question an include the required information to answer your question. You will probably be asked for more information like the installation log file but let’s just start with what you already intended to provide.

You will want to provide a screenshot of the folder that contains the setup executable.

My apoligies Ramhound. I did include the Configtration file/code but I forgot to inclose it in ````. Thats why it was not showing.

I tried to add two images to my question but for some reason the site only gives a url to them rather than showing the images within the post.

So you need to use Setup.exe or whatever the actual file name instead of Setup64.exe as for the reason it’s not prompting your which version that’s because you specify OfficeClientEdition in the configuration file. Without those screenshots I cannot help you. Just giving the URL is fine. Fix the formatting of your question for us.

Just want to point out the original revision of this question did not have the configuration file.

You add the images, then someone with sufficient reputation will edit your post to make the images show visibly. Low-rep users can only post image links for security reasons.

Please try following configuration file for a test.
<Configuration> 
<Add OfficeClientEdition="64"  
<Product ID="ProPlus2021Retail"> 
<Language ID="en-gb" /> 
<ExcludeApp ID="Groove" /> 
<ExcludeApp ID="Lync" /> 
<ExcludeApp ID="OneDrive" /> 
<ExcludeApp ID="OneNote" /> 
<ExcludeApp ID="Outlook" /> 
<ExcludeApp ID="PowerPoint" /> 
<ExcludeApp ID="Publisher" /> 
</Product> 
</Add> 
<RemoveMSI /> 
</Configuration> 

